# Cannot play a sound with Cron since recent system update (Ubuntu 19.10)

Tags: sound, alsa, cron, mplayer

Recently, after performing the routine update in my Ubuntu system (19.10), the command /usr/bin/play cannot play from Cron anymore (works fine on the command line). It was working great before for long time.

My script (which is called periodically by cron):

```
#! /bin/bash
...
/usr/bin/play <path-to-soundfile> 2> /tmp/log.txt
...
```

I get the error

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
/usr/bin/play FAIL sox: Sorry, there is no default audio device configured
```

I tried other players like mplayer, aplay and cvlc, but no luck. After doing some research about the issue, I tried these lines at the beginning of my bash script:

```
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/<userid>
export DISPLAY=:0
export XAUTHORITY=/home/<username>/.Xauthority
```

but to no avail.

Also, I added my user to the audio group. Still no change.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*not sure what will help, but ...*

**step 1**

```
xuser@mbs:~$ env|grep -i runt
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
```

**step 2** create file play.sh (remember about chmod)

```
#!/bin/bash
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
/usr/bin/mpg123 $1
```

**step 3** `crontab -e`

```
хх * * * * /home/xuser/bin/play.sh /home/xuser/Музыка/demo_moya_vesna.mp3
```

**step 4**

```
$%)) ata-ta %:) enjoy
```